# What does match function return because split is failing?

Tags: javascript

Via alert I have the information string 1:CX.PC.PB.0012.S.S which is from `alert(c_itemvalue);`

Then I have the line: `var arr = c_itemvalue.split(':');`

In Firefox I am getting an error `c_itemvalue.split(':') is not a function.`

Usually the only time I get not a function errors is when I'm trying to pass a variable of an invalid type (like is `c_itemvalue` was an integer) but this time the variable is the return from a match function so I assume that is a string value.

Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Can you post the HTML/JS that you are using?

Comment: Have you tried c_itemvalue.toString().split('.') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = c_itemvalue.toString().split(':');
```

The `c_itemvalue` might be not a string object

Comment: Ok this is dumb. Since I only have one return possible from the match, I assumed that I did not need to specify an index for the match. When using it as a string the value is found w/o hassle, but when using it as an object for split, you have to specify the index.

Answer (score 1):

The "match" function returns an array. The "alert" call will always ".toString()" its argument.